# In Python, what is the fastest way to ensure that an int is between two integers and adjust its value if necessary to keep in that range?

Tags: python, performance

In Python, what is the fastest way to ensure that an int is between two integers and adjust its value if necessary to keep in that range?

I can think of two approaches so far to ensure that x is between 0 and 100:

```
if x > 100:
    x = 100

if x < 0:
    x = 0
```

Or:

```
x = min(max(0, x), 100)
```

I wonder which is faster and if there is an even faster way?  I need to do this a lot in a loop for different x, typically x will be in the require range.

Comment: Consider using NumPy. It has [`clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html#numpy.clip).

Comment: Well,`if` and `elif` are mutually exclusive, so that will stop both conditions having to be checked on every iteration. Instead of using two `if`s

Comment: How many numbers are you doing this for?

Comment: Around 250,000 numbers.  It's for an algorithm that assigns a score from 0 to 100 to an entity but needs to ensure it says within those bounds.

Comment: Seems a bit much to import NumPy just for this though :)

Comment: But would be interesting to see how `clip` performs, once I have some time I'll add it to the comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Just to share what I have done so far, I created two files:

if.py

```
import timeit

s = """\
from random import randint

x = randint(-1, 102)

if x > 100:
    x = 100

if x < 0:
        x = 0
"""

print('if:', timeit.timeit(stmt=s))
```

min_max.py

```
import timeit

s = """\
from random import randint

x = randint(-1, 102)

x = min(max(0, x), 100)
"""

print('min_max:', timeit.timeit(stmt=s))
```

Then I ran:

```
python min_max.py; python if.py
```

The result has generally been consistent:

```
min_max: 11.23165112733841
if: 9.973816215991974
```

I figured since min/max are implemented in C they may be faster, but nope.

**UPDATE:** Based on the comments, I made the following changes:

- I changed the second if in if.py to an elif
- I moved the import statement into the setup

The new results are:

```
('min_max', 3.0133590698242188)
('if', 2.3094170093536377)
```

Comment: Yeah, but `min` and `max` are two function calls, which have a lot of overhead.

Comment: You should also move the `import` and the initial assign statement to the `setup=`. Performance will also depend on the possible range of numbers for `x` (for `[-1, 101]` the `if` branches are almost always skipped).

Comment: you're basically comparing random assignment time - remove all irrelevant code from the measured code

Comment: Yes, some code will be irrelevant but will be the same more or less constant for both, so the time different will still be valid.  I want to avoid hitting any optimizations by doing the same thing over and over or hitting a social case with comparing a particular number.